# Logics, how to transform sentences?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm studying the fundamental of logic of the first and second order. May i ask you how to translate this sentence in FOL?

Employees of ACME are nice and serious, but not everyone is funny

I have two ideas:

a) $\forall x$[ACME_Emp(x) $\Rightarrow$ Nice(x) $\land$ Serious(x) $\Rightarrow$ $\exists y$ (Funny(y) $\land$ ACME_Emp(y))]

b)$\forall x$[ACME_Emp(x) $\Rightarrow$ (Nice(x) $\land$ Serious(x) $\land$ Funny(x))] $\lor$ $\forall x$[ACME_Emp(x) $\Rightarrow$ (Nice(x) $\land$ Serious(x) $\land$ $\neg$Funny(x))]

In the first one i would say that only some of them (a few **y** individuals) are also funny.

The second one having an **or** means that each **x** must satisifes one of the 2 formuale

Comment: Don't use the same variable like that.

Comment: Implication is not associative, so you can't sensibly write $A\to B\to C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate it like this:
$$\forall x(Ex \to (Nx\land Sx))\land\exists y(Ey\land \lnot Fy),$$ where $Ex$ is "$x$ is an ACME employee", $Nx$ is "$x$ is nice", $Sx$ is "$x$ is serious", and $Fy$ is "$y$ is funny".

Comment: What about the second point? About the and instead of the implication @shaun

Comment: Because there are two clauses: "ACME employees are nice and serious" and "not everyone is funny". The former does not imply the latter. The correct connective is an "and", @ZhaledAsufian.

Comment: Yes but those who are funny are also nice and serious. So the second clause would be a subset of those that are funny and serious.it's not possible to have funny individuals that are not serious and nice!

Comment: Yes, but the first clause covers that.

Comment: So If i use the implication means that for every Person x Who satisifes the First clause, should exists another Person that satisfy the second one? This is why my version is wrong?

Comment: The first clause, indeed, is about *every* ACME employee.

Comment: I am certain that my answer is correct, @ZhaledAsufian.

Comment: So since every object x  of the domain is N and S, for sure if he become an y he will be also F, right? Wait, why you negated the funny F? Some of them are Funny so this would be affirmative! @Shaun

Comment: No, because the second clause states that $\exists y (Ey\land \lnot Fy)$, @ZhaledAsufian. Every element of the domain that is $E$ is indeed $N$ & $S$ by the first clause, so there's no need to repeat the assertion in the second clause.

Comment: Nowhere does it state that some of them are funny. It could be that they're all not funny.

Comment: Sure but i mean, since the sentence state that "Not every employee is funny", with the $\exists y$ we indicate those that are funny right? So why did you use $\neg F$ ? Thanks for your patience

Comment: No, @ZhaledAsufian. Think about it.

Comment: I used $\lnot Fy$ because not everyone is funny, so there must exist a $y$ such that $Ey\land\lnot Fy$.

Comment: yes but those who are funny where are expressed?

Comment: It could be that they are all not funny. Nowhere does it state that anyone is funny, @ZhaledAsufian.

Comment: All you need to do is ensure that there is at least one not funny employee, given that they are all nice and serious.

Comment: I'm getting crazy! So all of them are $N & S$ but only few of them are not funny. I mean this is tricky in plain english because i would think to something like " everyone is funny except a few of them" but here effectively no one said that they all are funny

Comment: Exactly, no-one said that they are all funny. The sentence is true still if there is only one nice & serious employee who is not funny.

Comment: No, it could be that they are all not funny.

Comment: Thanks man. For sake of curiosity, if i would have used $\exists y$ $F(y)$ this also implies automatically that all the other element that are not $y$ are not funny? Or is too tricky ?

Comment: If they are not $F$ then they are not funny.